# zero a esquerda (LPAD) no Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Como se faz em SqlServer para que o resultado venha com zero a esquerda ?

no mysql seria assim:

```
select lpad(mes,2,0 ) as 'mes', ano from tab_qualquer;
```

Como faz algo equivalente no Sql Server?

Já busquei no https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008 
e fiz assim:

```
select distinct
     right(replicate('0',2) + mes,2) as mes, 
     ano
from tabela
```

e deu o seguinte erro:

> Código do erro 0, estado do SQL 22019: Unrecognized SQL escape 'ano' at line position 702.
>   Linha 1, coluna 1

Comment: Esse select não iria retornar o que você precisa, mas também não era para dar erro. Poderia mostrar como está a estrutura de sua tabela? Quais os tipos dos atributos mes e ano

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se o campo mes for numérico, para exibir com zero à esquerda, vc deve demonstrá-lo como string. O Erro pode estar mascarando o real problema. Passe a estrutura da tabela.

```
select distinct
     right(replicate('0',2) + convert(VARCHAR,mes),2) as mes, 
     ano
from tabela
```

Comment: vlw, era o convert mesmo

Answer (score 3):

SEGUE:

```
Select REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(PER_CODIGO)) + RTrim(PER_CODIGO) FROM PERFIL
```

- '0' é o caracter que você quer que repita,
- 2 é quantidade de casas de sua string,
- 'PER_CODIGO' é o seu campo.

Answer (score 0):

Caso queira o exemplo abaixo funciona muito bem.

```
select RIGHT('000' + CAST('025' AS VARCHAR(10)),8)
```

Answer (score -1):

Se você apenas tirar as aspas do 0 também funciona, caso converter em VARCHAR não seja seu objetivo. Dessa forma você não precisa usar o convert.

```
 select distinct
     right(replicate(0,2) + mes,2) as mes, 
     ano
    from tabela
```

Dessa forma você retornaria o mês com dois caracteres e preencheria com 0 a esquerda caso ele tenha menos de 2 caracteres. Mantendo o tipo como NUMERIC.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).