# Como colocar zeros após o digito verificador - sql server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso colocar 9 zeros após o 02:

> 0207200000053P 02- aqui vai os zeros - 07200000053P

que está vindo de uma variável chamada `@vNossoNumero`. Como que eu faço isso?

**Variável**

```
Select  @vNossoNumero   = case when @Conta='0000064-7' then '16' else '02' end+RIGHT('00000000000' + convert(varchar,convert(bigint,@vSequencia) + 1),11)
```

Comment: [pad](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117208/64073)

Comment: Seria interessante se você demonstrasse o código que já tem pra podermos te ajudar

Comment: Da variável ele retorna assim:  Select  @vNossoNumero   = case when @Conta='0000064-7' then '16' else '02' end+RIGHT('00000000000' + convert(varchar,convert(bigint,@vSequencia) + 1),11)

Comment: E a outra string? vem de onde e vai pra onde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que a solução passa por algo deste género:

```
SELECT LEFT(@vNossoNumero, 2) + REPLICATE('0', 9) + RIGHT(@vNossoNumero, LEN(@vNossoNumero) - 2)
```

Ou assim:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 1, 2) + REPLICATE('0', 9) + SUBSTRING(@vNossoNumero, 3, LEN(@vNossoNumero))
```

Em ambos os casos o resultado serie, por exemplo:

> 0200000000007200000053P